# Can a C++20 [[likely]] or [[unlikely]] attribute be used on the condition of a do-while loop?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++20

I have tried placing `C++20`'s [`[[likely]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) and `[[unlikely]]` attributes at various locations around the condition of a `do`-`while` loop, and it seems placing them at the end of the line after the semicolon is accepted by all three major compilers:

```cpp
int main(int i, char**)
{
    do {
        ++i;
    } while (i < 42); [[likely]]

    return i;
}
```

However this looks rather strange. Is this really the correct place for the attribute?

Comment: The annotation is placed after the `;`.   So wouldn't the meaning be that the `return i` is likely to be executed?   Which .... um .... the compiler could infer without the annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a C++20 [[likely]] or [[unlikely]] attribute be used on the condition of a do-while loop?

`[[likely]]` cannot be applied on "conditions". It can be applied on labels and statements.

> However this looks rather strange. Is this really the correct place for the attribute?

You've applied the attribute to the return statement. If we adjust whitespace a bit, then you'll see it better:

```
} while (i < 42);

[[likely]] return i;
```

You should apply the attribute to the block statement that is the loop body:

```
do [[likely]] {
```